# what wrong with openldap cross compile?

Tags: cross-platform, mips, cross-compiling, openldap

I need to run OPENLDAP on MIPS platform,after cross-compiling,I got a `slapd`:

```
slapd: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS64 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.0, not stripped
```

However,when I ran `slapd` in tool mode and debug level,
something accured :

```
5630387c => bdb_last_id: get failed: DB_BUFFER_SMALL: User memory too small for return value (-30999)
5630387c bdb_db_open: database "dc=zkc,dc=cn": last_id(/usr/local/openldap/var/openldap-data) failed: DB_BUFFER_SMALL: User memory too small for return value (-30999).
5630387c backend_startup_one (type=bdb, suffix="dc=zkc,dc=cn"): bi_db_open failed! (-30999)
slap_startup failed (test would succeed using the -u switch)
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: now I did some change,the error is:`563079e3 bdb_monitor_db_open: monitoring disabled; configure monitor database to enable`(`DB_CONFIG` do exist in directory `var/openldap-data`)